# Как в название одной переменной записать много человек

Tags: python, ооп

Есть задача - нужно создать много аккаунтов для пользователей. То есть надо сделать так что бы при регистрации создавалась переменная '''user = User(name,passwd)''' и что бы и так для всех кто зарегается. И нужно сохранить их в user_dict так, что бы потом можно было найти их по имени и провести проверку логина и пароля. Как лучше всего сделать?

```
user_dict = []

class User:
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
        self.password = None
name = input('Введи имя')
user = User(name)
```

Comment: пароли лучше не хранить, а хранить их хеш

Answer (score 0):

```
user_dict = {}  # У словаря фигурные скобки, а не квадратные


class User:
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
        self.password = None


num = int(input('Введи количество новых записей: '))
for i in range(num):
    name = input('Введи имя: ')
    user_dict[name] = User(name)
```